# unregisterForRemoteNotifications doesn't work for iOS8 - Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, ios8, xcode6

I decided to turn off my notification on "reminders" switch control from my app. I added those lines in my app to make it support both iOS 7 and iOS 8 and it is working when I switched off push notification. BUT when I decided to turn on the switch and closed the app,when I opened it again and it went back to OFF instead of being ON. So I have to go to Settings --> Notification Center --> "my app" and turn all the things back on because they are off... Very strange that when I test it on iOS 7  it is working but not for iOS 8. Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks.

```
- (IBAction)reminderSwitchToggled:(id)sender {

      UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

      if ([sender isOn]) {

         #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
             if(NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
                 UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert categories:nil];
                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

             }
              else
         #endif
                 {
                   [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge| UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert| UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
                 }

     } else {

         #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
           if(NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {

               [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings
                                                                             settingsForTypes:
                                                                             (UIUserNotificationType)
                                                                             (UIUserNotificationTypeNone) 
                                                                             categories:nil]];

               [application unregisterForRemoteNotifications];

        }

          else
      #endif
          {
               [application unregisterForRemoteNotifications];

           }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should implement disabling push notifications on the server side. Apple docs said that you should call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

only if you will not provide notifications in app any more. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/unregisterForRemoteNotifications)

In other hand, iOS8 provides API to open Settings.app, where user can disable notifications for your app using switch control. Usage sample:

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```