# iOS: Disabling remote notifications if previously enabled

Tags: ios, push-notification

Once a user has either enabled or disabled remote notifications, do they have to be sent to settings to change that decision (enable if disabled, and vice versa)? We want to provide a switch in the app where they can turn Push Notifications on and off... but I don't really think that will be possible.

Comment: You can tell your server to stop sending push notifications to them when they turn off the switch in your app.  It won't have any effect on their settings for your app in the system settings.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you can not enable and disable push notification in inside the app.

You can check that user set enable or disable  Push Notifications using following code.

But you can manage it by adding switch and filtering in your server for users who have enabled the push. Like if you want to do Inside the app then use one identifier (or boolean) and send it to server according push notification enable and disable switcher. So, your server side coding use this identifier and work according to that. Like identifier is say it's enable than your server will send notification otherwise not.

Hope, this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

update the status on server and call below methods on toggle button push (On/OFF)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

refer below links

- [more about unregister](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457655/unregisterforremotenotifications-doesnt-work-for-ios8-push-notification)
- [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/unregisterForRemoteNotifications)